# How can I set custom path for file in the Advanced installer?

Tags: advanced-installer

I wanted to build an installer by using Advanced Installer. There are some files that do not need to install in the main application folder. I need to install them in the C:\ProgramData folder. How should I do that?

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ProgramData you need to place files in the **Common Application Data** folder.
Here is a list with the [paths for all the predefined folders.](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/folder-paths.html)

Also, here is how to [create a custom path folder](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-custom-folder.html) too.